# How to display all entries of an array within Chrome's, Firebug's and Firefox's console?

Tags: javascript, console, google-chrome-devtools, firebug, firefox-developer-tools

I have a simple snippet of code that reads the links from a web page and adds them to an array like this:

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('div.grid_imageContainer a[id^=detail_]');
var resp = [];
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
  resp.push(a[i].getAttribute('href'))
}
resp
```

If I copy this to Chrome's, Firebug's or Firefox's console, the result I get is limited, since I can't see the links completely, they have an ellipsis ('...') in the middle. But in Chrome if I click it, it shows me the full link. And in Firebug I can see the full link on hover.

It's a long list, so, how can I get the complete array to be printed?

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: `console.dir` or `console.table` as alternative s

Comment: `console.dir()` outputs the contents the same way as `console.log()` or the last line of the code above, but `console.table()` works at least in Firebug and the Firefox DevTools. The Chrome DevTools don't output a table when you pass the function the `resp` array.

Comment: console.table in firefox worked like a charm thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Firebug

Firebug has preference, which controls the maximal length of strings. To change it, go to [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config), search for [`extensions.firebug.stringCropLength`](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Preferences#stringCropLength) and change its value to `-1`.

Then you should always see the full strings.

## Chrome developer tools

As far as I know, there is no option to adjust the display of arrays within the console. So, you will have to expand the different parts manually or convert them into a string, e.g. by using `JSON.stringify()` as [mentioned by evolutionxbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39971246/432681#comment-67223068).

## Firefox developer tools

As far as I know, there is no option to adjust the display of arrays within the console, but you can click on the "more…" link to display the array entries in a side panel.
The strings are cropped dynamically in there, so you need to resize the side panel to see the complete strings.

They also allow you to output a list including the full strings using [`console.table()`](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console.table) (same in Firebug) as mentioned by Jaromanda X.

*Note: All three tools allow you to copy the array to the clipboard using the [`copy()`](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Copy) command, so you can paste it into your favorite text editor.*

Comment: Hello, console.table works as expected! But now I can't copy it.. could you give me an example of using copy() please? NVM I followed the link! My bad thanks!